# Is it possible to change Environment variable at Runtime in Aspnet Core. If yes then how?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, environment-variables

I want to change aspnet core env variable in runtime. I want to have a different DB context depending on the env and some others things too. Is it possible to change the Env variable at runtime?
Thank you...

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If you want a different DB connection depending on your environment, then you can specify the settings in the appSettings file and deploy a different settings file for each environmen you're going to deploy the application to. You can set up the publishing / deployment process such that it automatically deploys the correct version of the file to each environment.

Comment: in addition to @ADyson , the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ` is stored by default in the `web.config` file, you can change it and restart the server.

Comment: In order to determine the runtime environment, ASP.NET Core reads from the DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variables. When ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is called ConfigureWebHostDefaults. The default ASP.NET Core Web application template calls ConfigureWebHostDefaults. The ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value overrides DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT. If you want to use multiple environments, you can read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core /fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0